# 2001 Mk1 Renault Megane Central Locking Drivers Door Release

Tags: locks, renault

I have a 2001 Mk1 Renault Megane which has recently stopped unlocking the other doors when the driver's door is opened. The 'door open' indicator light also does not illuminate when the driver's door is open, but it does for the other doors.

- The door sensor switch is working OK since I have swapped it with one from another door and the problem remains.
- the connector block to the door sensor switch is getting 12V through it.
- The central locking will release if the button on the dashboard is pressed.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though there is a ground fault issue which is corrected when the door is closed. You'll need to check the wiring to see if there a break or partial break in it somewhere in the wiring harness going from the door back into the body.